# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, when trying to cover toInt()

Tags: swift

I am new in Swift and I am trying to build a simple program that converts the number of week in days, minutes and seconds, but i just cannot convert `String` to `Int`. When I thought it was done using `toInt()`, a message appeared in this line:

`var tempoEmDias:Int! = timeInDays.text.toInt()`,

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value...
```

Does anybody can help me? Code below...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var timeInDays: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var numberOfWeeks: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var numberOfHours: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var numberOfMinutes: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var numberOfSeconds: UILabel!


@IBAction func calculaTempo(sender: AnyObject) {

  // BELOW: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. 
    var tempoEmDias:Int! = timeInDays.text.toInt()



    // calcula semana

    var numeroDeSemanas:Int = 0


    if tempoEmDias! <= 7 {
        numeroDeSemanas = 1
    } else {

    numeroDeSemanas = tempoEmDias! / 7

    }

    let numeroDeSemanasCerto:Int = Int(numeroDeSemanas)

    numberOfWeeks.text = "/(numeroDeSemanasCerto) semanas"

    // calcula horas

    let numeroDeHoras = numeroDeSemanasCerto * 24
    numberOfHours.text = "/(numeroDeHoras) horas"

    // calcula minutos

    let numeroDeMinutos = numeroDeHoras * 60
    numberOfMinutes.text = "/(numeroDeMinutos) minutos"

    // calcula segundos

    let numeroDeSegundos = numeroDeMinutos * 60
    numberOfSeconds.text = "/(numeroDeSegundos) segundos"

}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you had no number in your `timeInDays` text field. In this case, `toInt()` returns `nil`, which you then assign to an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: yes, but how can I treat this error in the code?

Comment: `I am new in Swift`, like we all :)

Comment: If you just want an easy fix, write: `var tempoEmDias:Int = timeInDays.text.toInt() ?? 0` and then remove all the unwraps (`!`s) from later uses of the variable. But you should also go ahead and learn what optionals are and what they are good for. Apple's Swift documentation will help you there.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because toInt() returns an optional integer value and you are trying assign it to non-optional `tempoEmDias`.

from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/String):

```
toInt()

Use this method to convert a string to an integer value.
The method returns an optional integer value (Int?)—if the conversion succeeds,
the value is the resulting integer; if the conversion fails, the value is nil:

let string = "42"
if let number = string.toInt() {
    println("Got the number: \(number)")
} else {
    println("Couldn't convert to a number")
}
// prints "Got the number: 42"
```

Comment: It is very strange. It works in playground but no in the project when running the simulator.

Comment: 'when running the simulator'? So it's runtime error?

Comment: I wrote the code again and it did work well. See below

    @IBAction func btnGreet(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        var theName:String = txtName.text     
        var dias = theName.toInt()  
        var numeroDeSemanas:Int = 0  
        if dias <= 7 {
            numeroDeSemanas = 1
        } else {   
            numeroDeSemanas = dias! / 7
        }   
        lblResult.text = "\(numeroDeSemanas) semanas" 
        // calcula horas
        let numeroDeHoras = dias! * 24
        lbHoras.text = "\(numeroDeHoras) horas"  
    }